# Visual Studio Code empties html files on save

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm trying to save an html file in visual studio code, all the code is deleted and the empty file is saved. I have this issue in all folders and projects I even reinstalled vscode but I still can't save html files. Other filetypes work and editors like atom and notepad++ don't have that problem on my machine.

Does anybody know how I can solve the issue or are there any logfiles for debugging?

Comment: Can you try disabling all extensions and restarting vscode to see if one of them is causing this?

Comment: After starting vscode with "code --disable-extensions" html saving worked again. I was able to identify the extension "vscode-tidyhtml" as the culprit. Thank you so much!